# Projective ideals of $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{180\mathbb{Z}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, projective-module

Determine all the projective ideals of the ring $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{180\mathbb{Z}}$. Give an example of an ideal that is not projective.

We can begin by applying the CRT to find some of the projective ideals but that would not give us all of them. Then we can utilize the fact that if I is a projetive ideal there exist $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{180\mathbb{Z}}$-module M such that

$$(\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{180\mathbb{Z}})^{(I)} \cong I \oplus M.$$

Now, if the LHS was $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{180\mathbb{Z}}$ we could have said that I is in the form of  $eR$  where $e$ is an idempotent element of the the ring $R=\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{180\mathbb{Z}}$. So, we could characterize all the projective ideals by idempotents. I don't know how to remedy the situation.

Comment: How do you find the projective ideals of Z/p^r? In addition, If the CRT determines all of the projective ideals then how do we rule out something like Z/aZ where a is not power of a prime? I mean which theorem do you use? @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez

Comment: So, the only projective ideals are the ones that are given by the CRT? On a related question, what if we replace projective by injective in the statement? In this case, we can apply Baer theorem to deduce that the ring itself is injective and then appealing to the CRT will give us all the injective ideals? @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez

Comment: I will do tomorrow I guess because it's getting late here. But to clarify, what I meant was as per your comment the projective ideals of Z/p^r consist of only one ideal, which is  Z/p^r itself. Now, the CRT gives us a decomposition in terms of these ideals, namely Z/p^r's. So, I meant these are all the projective ideals of Z/180Z, right?@MarianoSuárez-Álvarez